# Could not printf a const char* after running the own function "strAppend"

Tags: c

I am not sure why the last printf command did not produce any printout. I could not find the answer after searching stack overflow site. Can someone shred the light on this issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// append s2 to s1 (char s1[])
void strAppend(char s1[], const char *s2)
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len2; i++)
    {
        s1[i + len1] = s2[i];
    }
    s1[len2 + len1] = '\0';
}

int main()
{

    char str[] = "hi:";
    const char *str1 = "hello ";
    printf("str1: %s\n", str1); //expected printout 
    strAppend(str, str1);
    printf("appended str: %s\n", str); //expected printout
    printf("str1: %s\n", str1); // no printout
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you allocating memory?

Comment: The definition `char str[] = "hi:";` creates an array of exactly four elements, No more, no less. Arrays in C are not dynamic, you can't extend an array. Once its size have been set, it can't change. Therefore when you try to append to it, you will write out of bounds. That will lead to *undefined behavior*. You need to make sure the destination array is large enough to hold both strings (and the null-terminator).

Comment: Try `char str[200] = "hi:";` in order to allocate sufficient memory in `str`.

Comment: Or you can dynamically allocate memory if needed.

Comment: Thank you for all commemts. I am wondering why the second printf produces the expected result. str[] has four elements by defineing char str[] = "hi:".

Comment: ***Undefined behavior*** can mean anything could happen, from a crash, to weird or unexpected behavior, or seemingly working just fine.